# Cascading HP StorageWorks MSA60 and MSA50

Tags: storage, sas

We currently have a cascade of two MSA50 arrays connected to a P600 controller. Is it possible to add a MSA60 array to the cascade? HP documentation states that MSA60 is compatible with P600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a P600 (or a P800 for that matter) you can only have two disk enclosures per external channel - i.e. a primary MSA then a secondary one daisy-chainedp600. That said you can mix MSAs, primary can be a 50, secondary can be a 60 or 70 etc. Obviously you won't be able to effectively create an array combining the disks from both a 50 and 60 due to the slight differences in disk sizes (2.5 vs 3.5 inch disks) but you'll be able to have two arrays.

edit - be careful with the SAS cables you use by the way, there's two connector types and it's easy to get the wrong ones :)

Comment: Thanks for the information. By the way, where I can read the specs on the max number of daisy-changed arrays? I haven't been able to find it on the official P600 page.

Comment: In a way here as I know for a fact you can only cascade two boxes per external port :) We have one platform with over a thousand 50s and 70s so I've been through a lot of learning/pain with them over the years. Here's the quickspecs anyway; http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12247_na/12247_na.pdf

Comment: My pleasure, it was a good question.